# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: java, spring, oracle, sessionfactory, hibernate-5.x

I am designing web app with spring-boot + hibernate 5. And I am not using any xml files. I am creating data source and sessionFactory, and I am getting error:

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

But my username and password are exactly right.
It is my dataSource bean:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUsername("system");
        dataSource.setPassword("admin");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");

        return dataSource;
    }
```

It is my sessionFactory bean:

```
@Autowired
@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
public SessionFactory generateSessionFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
    DriverManagerDataSource ds = (DriverManagerDataSource)dataSource;
    System.out.println(ds.getUsername() + " " + ds.getPassword());
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = 
            new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = sessionBuilder
            .scanPackages("org.company")    
            .setProperties(getHibernateProperties())
            .buildSessionFactory();

    return sessionFactory;
}
```

It is my getHibernateProperties() method, which is used in sessionFactory:

```
public Properties getHibernateProperties(){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql",  "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    return properties;
}
```

And I have hibernate.properties file just in case:

```
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
hibernate.connection.username = system  
hibernate.connection.user = system
hibernate.connection.password = admin
hibernate.connection.driver_class = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Part of stack trace:

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
 '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.3.RELEASE)

2016-04-17 12:59:52.312  INFO 5136 --- [           main] org.company.RestresourceApplication      : Starting RestresourceApplication on РњРѕСЂС„РџРљ with PID 5136 (D:\NewWorkspace\restresource\target\classes started by РњРѕСЂС„ in D:\NewWorkspace\restresource)
2016-04-17 12:59:52.317  INFO 5136 --- [           main] org.company.RestresourceApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-04-17 12:59:52.424  INFO 5136 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@22f17321: startup date [Sun Apr 17 12:59:52 EEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-04-17 12:59:54.527  INFO 5136 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2016-04-17 12:59:55.607  INFO 5136 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$df212fee] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-04-17 12:59:56.878  INFO 5136 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-04-17 12:59:56.898  INFO 5136 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-04-17 12:59:56.899  INFO 5136 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
2016-04-17 12:59:57.109  INFO 5136 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-04-17 12:59:57.110  INFO 5136 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4698 ms
2016-04-17 12:59:57.905  INFO 5136 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-04-17 12:59:57.911  INFO 5136 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-04-17 12:59:57.912  INFO 5136 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-04-17 12:59:57.912  INFO 5136 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-04-17 12:59:57.913  INFO 5136 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-04-17 12:59:58.110  INFO 5136 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
2016-04-17 13:00:00.223  INFO 5136 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-04-17 13:00:00.280  INFO 5136 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-04-17 13:00:00.631  INFO 5136 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.5.Final}
2016-04-17 13:00:00.636  INFO 5136 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.connection.username=system  , hibernate.connection.password=****, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect, hibernate.connection.user=system, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver}
2016-04-17 13:00:00.637  INFO 5136 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-04-17 13:00:00.738  INFO 5136 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2016-04-17 13:00:00.758  WARN 5136 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000006: Attempted to specify unsupported NamingStrategy via setting [hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy]; NamingStrategy has been removed in favor of the split ImplicitNamingStrategy and PhysicalNamingStrategy; use [hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy] or [hibernate.physical_naming_strategy], respectively, instead.
2016-04-17 13:00:01.295  WARN 5136 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

2016-04-17 13:00:01.325  INFO 5136 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
2016-04-17 13:00:01.376  INFO 5136 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
2016-04-17 13:07:53.993 ERROR 7432 --- [           main] org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper   : Unable obtain JDBC Connection

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:385) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:938) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:480) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:416) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:825) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:596) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:130) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$2.obtainConnection(SessionFactoryImpl.java:648) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper.executeIdTableCreationStatements(IdTableHelper.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.prepare(AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) [hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) [spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) [spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319) [spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.company.RestresourceApplication.main(RestresourceApplication.java:112) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_73]

2016-04-17 13:07:54.006  INFO 7432 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-04-17 13:07:54.162  WARN 7432 --- [           main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker        : [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 49 in HQL: [from org.company.model.User user where userId = ?].  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
system admin
2016-04-17 13:07:54.386  WARN 7432 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections            : HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
2016-04-17 13:07:54.390  INFO 7432 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections            : HHH10001005: using driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe]
2016-04-17 13:07:54.390  INFO 7432 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections            : HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=system    , password=****}
2016-04-17 13:07:54.393  INFO 7432 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections            : HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
2016-04-17 13:07:54.399  INFO 7432 --- [           main] .c.i.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl : HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
2016-04-17 13:07:54.451  WARN 7432 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.company.service.UserService org.company.controller.UserController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.company.dao.UserDAO org.company.service.UserServiceImpl.userDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.company.dao.UserDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in org.company.RestresourceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'generateSessionFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2016-04-17 13:07:54.456  INFO 7432 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-04-17 13:07:54.461  INFO 7432 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-04-17 13:07:54.508 ERROR 7432 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The error is really clear isnt it .. The username and password doesen't exist in the DB which you are trying to access. Can you access the DB using the same username and password from outside of your application ?

Comment: Yes, I access to DB from SQL developer, and result is successfull. And I have another web app with xml files, and that application works good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible, that you have whitespace in your hibernate.properties hibernate.connection.username? Guessing from logging output:

```
{hibernate.connection.username=system  ,
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't understand, why hibernate get properties from this file, but not from my dataSource, and when I delete hibernate.properties file, I get error: Application should supply JDBC connection. Explain me please, why hibernate can't get properties from dataSource??

Comment: When you are creating  ` new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource)`, spring adds hibernate.connection.datasource property for your datasource. But when you are building SessionFactory calling .setProperties(getHibernateProperties()) will replace current set of properties. Try to use addProperties method instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a bug in oracle.
you enter the username and password right. but it is sent in a different way, it could be change of your password from uppercase to lowercase or lowercase to uppercase. I solved this problem by changing my oracle password to uppercase. 
you should try it too.